# Optional text printed in another colour

Tags: environments, conditionals

I would like to extend the `version` package to print some optionally added text in a different colour. Something like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{version}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\includeversion{mynote} % Like this it works.
%\excludeversion{mynote} % Like this it doesn't work.
\newenvironment{note}{\begin{mynote}\color{red}}{\end{mynote}}
\begin{document}
Some text. \begin{note}And a note.\end{note} And some more text.
\end{document}
```

If I comment in the `\includeversion{mynote}` line it works:

[image: output]

But if I switch to the `\excludeversion{mynote}` line I get the following:

```
Runaway argument?


! File ended while scanning use of \@Vii@ExcludeToEnd.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

Comment: Why should you use `\excludecomments{mynote}` if it's `note` that you don't want to show?

Comment: @egreg Do you mean I should have done the encapsulation some other way round? How would I do that?

Comment: @muk.li: The alternative is to use `\excludecomments{note}`, of course.

Comment: @muk.li I don't understand the reason for the encapsulation to begin with; but if it's `note` you want to hide, just use `\excludecomments{note}`.

Comment: @egreg Actually I want the note, if it is displayed, to automatically be printed in red colour. That's why I did the encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\end{mynote}` is not seen as part of the input stream, as it's hidden within `\end{note}`. You can use a different technique and capture the entire `note` environment contents before passing it to a "clean" (or more visible) `mynote` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{version,xcolor,environ}
%\includeversion{mynote} % Like this it works.
\excludeversion{mynote} % Like this it works.
%\newenvironment{note}{\begin{mynote}\color{red}}{\end{mynote}}
\NewEnviron{note}{\begin{mynote}\color{red}\BODY\end{mynote}}
\begin{document}
Some text. \begin{note}And a note.\end{note} And some more text.
\end{document}
```

[`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) allows you to capture the environment contents inside `\BODY`.

Comment: This doesn't print the text in the note in red.

Comment: @muk.li: Sorry, I forgot to transfer the `\color{red}` insertion.

Comment: One thing I noted is that this way of doing it eats up the space after the environment, so that you get a `note.And some more text.` From the `environ` documentation I get that that's a feature, which, it seems, can be disabled by appending a `[]` to the end of the environment definition with `\NewEnviron`.